# What's the point of "make move" and "undo move" in chessengines?

Tags: chess

I want to experiment with massive parallel chess computing. From what I saw and understood in wikis and source code of some engines is that in most (all?) implementations of the min-max(negamax, alpha-beta, ...)-algorithm there is one internal position that gets updated for every new branch and then gets undone after receiving the evaluation of that branch.

What are the benefits of that technic compared to just generating a new position-object and passing that to the next branch?
This is what I have done in my previous engines and I believe this method is superior for the purpose of parallelism.

Comment: It depends on the size of the position object. If it is large, making a copy might use more memory bandwidth than a small update and a move-back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends heavily on a few factors, such as how you are storing the chess board, and what your make/unmake move function looks like. I'm sure there are ways of storing the board that would be better suited towards your method, and indeed historically some top tiered chess engine (in particular crafty) used to use that method, but you are correct in saying that modern engines no longer do it that way. Here is a link to a discussion about this very point:
http://www.talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=50805

If you want to understand why this is, then you must understand how today's engines represent the board. The standard implementation revolves around bitboards, and that requires 12- 64 bit integers per position, in addition to a redundant mailbox (array in non computer chess jargon) used in conjunction. Copying all that is usually more expensive than a ***good*** makeMove/unMakeMove function.

I also want to point out that a hybrid approach is also common. Usually make and unmake is used on the board itself, where as other information like en passant squares and castle rights are copied and changed like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, for board representations of < ~300 bytes, it IS cheaper to copy the board on each move (on modern x86), as opposed to making and unmaking the move.

As you suggest the immutable properties of copying the board on each move are from a programming perspective, including parallelising, very attractive.

My board rep is 208 bytes. C++ compiled with g++ 7.4.0.

Empricism shows that board copy is 20% faster than move make/unmake. I presume the code is using 32/64 byte-wide AVX instructions for the copy. In theory you can do 32/64 byte copy per cycle.

Just for you: https://github.com/rolandpj1968/oom-skaak/tree/init-impl-legal-move-gen-move-do-undo-2